# Secure Symmetric key from sa

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption

Can I secure SQL Server symmetric key from [sa] account? Can I create symmetric key using local user certificate via MMC?

Thanks

Comment: [BACKUP MASTER KEY failing with cannot find symmetric master key because it does not exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/184805)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I secure SQL Server symmetric key from [sa] account?

Nope. The best you can do (and should be doing) is to:

1. Rename SA
2. Use Windows authentication only
3. Disable SA (also see #2)

However, SA is just a login. The server roles of sysadmins gives full privileges over the system.

The only way to secure a symmetric key using SQL Server against a sysadmins is to use multiple encryption techniques involving the users and/or the application.

*Note that always encrypted and HSMs use Asymmetric keys.*

> Can I create symmetric key using local user certificate via MMC?

That's not going to help you with this issue.

Comment: Note that if you encrypt the Symmetric Key with only a password, then a sysadmin would have debug the instance or attack the TRIPPLE_DES key derived from the password to open your Key.

Comment: Correct @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I meant that as part of the "involving the users and or the application" part. If it's not clear enough I can break it out further.